# Как обратиться к маркеру через _leaflet_id?

Tags: javascript, map, mapbox

Первый раз создаю карту на основании mapbox. В нижеуказанном коде при нажатии на карту создаю группу и маркером и кругом.

```js
var marker, circle, group, removeName, classGroup, idGroup = 1;
map.on('click', function(e) {
    var nameGroup = prompt('Введіть назву маркера', 'Новый маркер '+idGroup);
    if (nameGroup == null) return;
    circle_radius = prompt('Введіть радіус маркера', 300);
    if (circle_radius == null) return;
    marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(myLayer);
    circle = L.circle([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, {draggable: true}], circle_radius, circle_options).addTo(myLayer);
    group = L.featureGroup([marker, circle])
        .bindPopup(nameGroup)
        .on('click', function() {
            map.removeLayer(this);
            removeName = this._leaflet_id;
            removeLi(removeName);
        })
        .addTo(map);
    classGroup = group._leaflet_id;
    addLi(nameGroup, classGroup);
    group.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        e.layer.openPopup();
    });
    group.on('mouseout', function(e) {
        e.layer.closePopup();
    });
    idGroup++;
});
```

Так же после их создания на sidebar'e появляется li с именем нашего маркера и в `id` нашего li находиться `_leaflet_id` этого же маркера.

```js
function addLi(nameGroup, classGroup) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("item");
    var div = document.createElement("li");
    div.setAttribute('class', 'item');
    div.setAttribute('id', classGroup);
    div.innerHTML = nameGroup.toString();
    elem.parentNode.appendChild(div, elem);
    div.addEventListener('click', openPopup)
}
```

Было задумано что при нажатии на наш li:

```js
function openPopup(){
    var nameMarker = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(nameMarker);
    var selectMarker = group._leaflet_id = nameMarker;
    selectMarker.openPopup();
}
```

будет всплывать наш `bindPopup()`, но я не могу корректно обратиться к нашей группе/маркеру по `_leaflet_id`

Comment: Нашел решение: создал массив `var allGroups = []` и при создании группы пушил её в наш новый массив: `allGroups.push(group);`
Потом написал небольшой цикл: `for (var i = 0; i < allGroups.length; i++) {
        if(allGroups[i]._leaflet_id == nameMarker) {
            allGroups[i].openPopup();
        }
    }`

Comment: добавь с помощью правки свой ответ в твой вопрос, и напиши что это ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение: создал массив var allGroups = [] и при создании группы пушил её в наш новый массив: allGroups.push(group); Потом написал небольшую функцию:

```js
function openPopup(){
    var nameMarker = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(nameMarker);
    for (var i = 0; i < allGroups.length; i++) {
        if(allGroups[i]._leaflet_id == nameMarker) {
            allGroups[i].openPopup();
        }
    }
}
```